# Spring's ContentLoaderListener not found in the web-app but was found on the system classpath

Tags: spring, gwt, web.xml

I am building a GWT app with Spring. I am having some issues to inject a dependency to one of my Servlets, so I am trying to narrow down what can be wrong.

First, when my app starts I get:

> [WARN] Server class
>   'org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener'
>   could not be found in the web app, but
>   was found on the system classpath
>   [WARN] Adding classpath entry
>   'file:/home/macarse/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6/spring-2.5.6.jar'
>   to the web app classpath for this
>   session    For additional info see:
>   file:/home/macarse/tpf/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.4_2.0.4.v201006301309/gwt-2.0.4/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
>   [WARN] Server class
>   'org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap'
>   could not be found in the web app, but
>   was found on the system classpath
>   [WARN] Adding classpath entry
>   'file:/home/macarse/tpf/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.4_2.0.4.v201006301309/gwt-2.0.4/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this
>   session    For additional info see:
>   file:/home/macarse/tpf/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.4_2.0.4.v201006301309/gwt-2.0.4/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
>   Jul 18, 2010 11:07:00 AM
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext INFO: Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization
>   started Jul 18, 2010 11:07:00 AM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@16b904d:
>   display name [Root
>   WebApplicationContext]; startup date
>   [Sun Jul 18 11:07:00 ART 2010]; root
>   of context hierarchy Jul 18, 2010
>   11:07:00 AM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   obtainFreshBeanFactory INFO: Bean
>   factory for application context
>   [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@16b904d]:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a8dfb3
>   Jul 18, 2010 11:07:01 AM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   preInstantiateSingletons INFO:
>   Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a8dfb3:
>   defining beans []; root of factory
>   hierarchy Jul 18, 2010 11:07:01 AM
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext

Is that OK?

In my `web.xml` I have:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:/META-INF/spring-presentation.xml, classpath*:/META-INF/spring-persistence.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is there a way to know if those two xml were loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan your application startup logs. You should find logs telling you which context files it loaded in the following format (log pattern might differ based on your log config):

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader (315): Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/META-INF/spring-presentation.xml]

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader (315): Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/META-INF/spring-persistence.xml]

Comment: with your answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283884/spring-xml-files-outside-web-inf I solved my issue. Thanks.